# read data from the table view

Tags: iphone

how do i read the content displayed in the table.
My case is : i have a table where i display the values from string array .
now when i select a particular row, i want to read the contents of the selected row of the table.
i tried reading the data from the NSMutable array, but does not work.
Please help

Comment: reading the data from the NSMutable array, that we use as a datasource to the table

Comment: You should paste some code containing the access of the data array.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use

> ```
> [[[myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text]
> ```

in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Or you want to know something else?